# Adding AD group to another AD group

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to add an AD group to another AD group but in a different forest.
There's a trust between these 2 domains.

```
$DomainA = "<domain>"
$DomainB = "<different domain>"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "<ad group name>" -Server $DomainA -Members "<ad group name>" -Server $DomainB
```

What is the best way to cross add the groups?

Error I receive:
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Server' is specified more than once. To provide multiple values to parameters that can accept multi
ple values, use the array syntax.

Comment: `-Server` should be for resolving `-Identity`. `-Members` may need to have their DN values.

Comment: {$Group = Get-ADGroup "AD group" -Server $DomainA
$Group1 = Get-ADGroup "AD group" -Server $DomainB

Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $Group1}

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You cannot specify `-Server` twice. Your question (in essence) is even covered in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember) (example 4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the param server only once, either DomainA or DomainB.

Make sure the group names have their respective domains prefixed i.e. DomainA\GroupName.

As an example, GroupB in DomainB would become a member of GroupA in DomainA :

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "DomainA\GroupA" -Members "DomainB\GroupB" -Server "DomainA"
```